# Service class does not run

Tags: multithreading, javafx, service

I have the following section of JavaFX that implements `Service` class:

```
public void processingImage() {

    Task<Void> track = new Task<Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {

            while (true) {
                if (flag == false) {
                   if (someCondition) {
                        flag = true;
                        CommunicateServer.sendObject = new Object[2];
                        CommunicateServer.sendObject[0] = 6;
                        CommunicateServer.sendObject[1] = "hello";

                        myService.start();
                        flag = false;

                        System.out.println("this line does not print");
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
    Thread th1 = new Thread(track);
    th1.setDaemon(true);
    th1.start();
}
```

And the `MyService` class is implemented as:

```
private class MyService extends Service<Void> {

    @Override
    protected Task<Void> createTask() {
        return new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {

                  CommunicateServer.callSendObject(CommunicateServer.sendObject, true);
                   response = CommunicateServer.getObject();
                   System.out.println("this print should have been many times but only executed once!!!!");

                return null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

My problem is although I expect the code to print `this line does not print`, the code actually does not print this. Moreover, the line `this print should have been many times but only executed once!!!!` is printed only once although I think it should have been printed many times. I don't know how to fix this problem. Any help or suggestion will be met with gratitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what you expect your code to do, but `Service.start()` [should be called from the FX Application Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html#start--). Since you are calling it from a background thread, this may be throwing an exception, preventing you reaching the `System.out.println(...)` statement.

Moreover, the service must be in the `READY` state to receive the call to `start()`, so on the second execution (if there is one), since the service has not been reset, you will get an `IllegalArgumentException`, exiting the `call()` method in the task defined in `processingImage()`. Hence your service will execute at most once.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That worked!!!!! I was not sure but gradually I learned it :)